# ¿Como ajustar el ancho de columnas de una grilla a su contenido y permitir que se pueda modificar manualmente en Pascal?

Tags: delphi, pascal

Estoy programando en pascal y utilizo Delphi Xe7. Estoy tratando de hacer que el ancho de las columnas de una grilla se ajuste a su contenido, pero que permita modificar el ancho a gusto del usuario.La grilla es una `TStringAlignGrid` y este es el codigo que utilizo para que se ajuste al contenido:

```
procedure TfPlanillaOrdenPreparacion.gDetalleDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer; Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  vWidth : Integer;
begin
  if (FormPosition.WMaximized = True) then
  begin
    vWidth := gDetalle.Canvas.TextWidth(gDetalle.Cells[ACol, ARow]);
    if vWidth > aColWidthExpanded[ACol] then
      aColWidthExpanded[ACol] := vWidth+20;
    gDetalle.ColWidths[ACol] := aColWidthExpanded[ACol];
  end;
end;
```

Al momento de cargar los datos, se cargan correctamente en la grilla y se ajustan al contenido como tiene que ser, pero cuando quiere agrandar o reducir alguna columna, no lo puedo hacer. Es como se que deshabilita la propiedad que me deja modificar el ancho. No entiendo que estoy haciendo mal, soy bastante nuevito en delphi xe7, les agradezco su ayuda :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El comportamiento que describes tiene sentido, ya que estás cambiando el tamaño de la celda en el evento `DrawCell`, que se ejecuta cada vez que se dibuja la celda (no solo antes de que el usuario ajuste el tamaño, sino que también después.

Lo que habitualmente se hace en situaciones como esta, es tener un método separado, para ajustar el ancho de la columna solo cuando hace falta, por ejemplo, luego de *cargar* información en el grid.

El método para ajustar de manera automática el ancho de la columna puede ser similar a este:

```
procedure TfPlanillaOrdenPreparacion.AdjustColumnWidthBestFit(AGrid: TStringAlignGrid;
  AColumn: Integer);
var
  MaxWidth, CellWidth, I: Integer;
begin
  //acá asegurate que el canvas tenga el font correcto para la columna, si utilizas distintos fonts.
  MaxWidth := 30; //este es el ancho mínimo de la columna
  for I := 0 to AGrid.RowCount - 1 do
  begin
    CellWidth := AGrid.Canvas.TextWidth(AGrid.Cells[AColumn, I]);
    if CellWidth > MaxWidth then
      MaxWidth := CellWidth;
  end;
  aColWidthExpanded[AColumn] := MaxWidth + 8;
  AGrid.ColWidths[AColumn] := aColWidthExpanded[ACol];
end;
```

Que luego llamas cuando convenga, por ejemplo el código siguiente llamaría al método para ajustar todas las columnas luego de cargar los datos de un archivo de texto:

```
procedure TfPlanillaOrdenPreparacion.CargarDatos;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  gDetalle.LoadFromFile('detalle.txt');
  for I := 0 to gDetalle.ColumnCount - 1 do
    AdjustColumnWidthBestFit(gDetalle, I);
end;
```

De esta forma, como ya no tocas de manera programática el ancho de las columnas más adelante, el usuario tendrá la libertad de hacerlas más chicas o más grandes a su gusto.
Puedes también agregar una manera para que el usuario re-ajuste la columna al ancho del contenido, por ejemplo al hacer doble clic en el título de una columna, invocas de nuevo al método `AdjustColumnWidthBestFit` y listo.